# Why is multiple arrays being printed out?

Tags: python

So as the title suggest, I'm having some trouble figuring out why there are 3 arrays being printed instead of them all appending to the same array. My goal is to check all the numbers in x is less than 10, if they are, append them to y. This is the code I wrote

```
x = [7, 13, 11, 2, 53, 95, 0.05]
y = []

for num in x:
  if(num<10):
    y.append(num)
     print(y)
```

And this is the result I'm getting...

```
[7]
[7,2]
[7,2,0.05]
```

How do i get them the values to append to the same array?
And why are they even splitting up in different arrays and showing only one number per line?

Comment: they are all the same list, your print statement is within the for loop

Comment: Thank you! I quick-fixed it by printing y outside of the loop :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting more than one because your print statement is inside the loop. Try this:

```
x = [7, 13, 11, 2, 53, 95, 0.05]
y = []

for num in x:
  if(num<10):
    y.append(num)

print(y) # outside of loop
```

Comment: Yeah, noticed that! Thank you for the answer, now it makes sense that it prints in multiple times on different lines :D